# How to count the leaves of a tree without a outside function counter?

Tags: algorithms, recursion

I got bombed in a interview because I was asked to write an algorithm which would count the leaves of a tree, I did this:

```
class TreeNode{
TreeNode[] children;
int value;

ctor(){
 children = new TreeNode[]();
}
}

class CountingClass{
int count;

ctor(){
count = 0;
}

void Count(TreeNode node)
{
 if(node.Children.Count > 0)
 {
   foreach(TreeNode item in node.Children)
   {
     Count(item);
   }
 }
 count++;
}


}
```

the interviewer appreciated demostrating my OOP approach but he wanted a  solution contained in the function.

I got nervours and gave up after 20 minutes figuring it out. I was trying to pass an int as ref in the param but he said that is not what he was looking for either.

What is that thing I am missing here?

Comment: To count leaf nodes, you need to increment `count` only when a `node` has zero children.

Comment: Sample recursive function - https://gist.github.com/nangalvivek/85186f527799f3611edcd04e0341bb2b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the leaves of the tree via a simple recursive function. Implement `count_leaves(TreeNode node)` as follows:

- If `node.children` is empty, return `1` as this node is a leaf itself
- Otherwise, return the sum of `count(child)` for all `child` in `node.children`

No external counters or complicated passing is needed.